# How is the following expresson be obtained and the meaning of the expression in blue box?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

[image]

Let me introduce the term {$E_\lambda:\lambda \geq0$} is the spectral resolution of identity of a self adjoint densely defined, positive and closed operator $A:D(A)\subset X\rightarrow X$ , Where X be the Hilbert space. And $f:[0,T]\rightarrow X$ is a function having eigenfunction expression $f(t)=\int_{0}^{T}exp(2\lambda s)d||E_\lambda f(s)||^{2}ds <\infty$ and $A_\epsilon$ is a positive real number. The expression above the blue box is fine. But I can not understand, how the expression in blue box is obtained and what is the meaning of the expression in sky colour box in Hilbert space. I have god this expression in time of reading a paper on back ward heat conduction problem namely ''A simple regularization method for ill-posed evolution equation ''  by Nguyen Huy Tuan, Dang Duc Trong, Ho Chi Minh City. Please help me to understand the things.

Comment: what is $\varphi$?

Comment: @user66081 sorry for not mentioning. $\phi$ is an element of Hilbert space.

Comment: The def of $f$ does not make sense to me. Where is $t$ and what is $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the first line,
\begin{align}
u(t) - u_\epsilon(t)
& =
\int_{A_\epsilon}^\infty 
e^{-\lambda t} 
d E_\lambda
\left(
e^{\lambda T} \varphi
-
\int_t^T e^{\lambda s} f(s) ds
\right)
\end{align}
so the squared norm of this expression is (recall that $E_\lambda$ is a projector on the Hilbert space)
\begin{align}
\| u(t) - u_\epsilon(t) \|^2
& =
\int_{A_\epsilon}^\infty 
e^{-2\lambda t} 
\left\|
d E_\lambda
\left(
e^{\lambda T} \varphi
-
\int_t^T e^{\lambda s} f(s) ds
\right)
\right\|^2
.
\end{align}
The notation would make more sense if the spectral measure was discrete, which I recommend writing down if you are confused about it.

So it seems to me that the estimate in the first box just contains a bunch of extra terms, and $(\cdots)^2$ means $\|\cdots\|^2$.

The second box is obtained from this expression by setting $\varepsilon = 0$ and $t = 0$ (I am guessing from the first expression that $u_\varepsilon = 0$ for $\varepsilon = 0$).

Comment: so you are saying that you have interchange the integral by applying fubini theorem and calculate the $||u(t)-u_\epsilon(t)||^{2}$. Also you are saying that in second  box the term is nothing but square of norm which is given in first bracket . that is why i am confused. thank you. how do you cheek fubini criterion please explain me.

Comment: @AjoyJana: good question; one would require a vector-valued Fubini here

Comment: $t$ is non negative and less than $T$ and $\epsilon$ is positive

Comment: How can you write $exp(\lambda T)$ in $dE_\lambda exp(\lambda T)...... $?  the differential depend on $\lambda$.